# Removing sudo from Pi default user

Tags: sudo

I have strange bahaviour from my Pi.

My /etc/sudoers looks like:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

user Pi belongs to:

```
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi) groups=1000(pi),20(dialout),29(audio),44(video),46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),101(input),108(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)
```

How ever it have absolutely no problem using sudo like root... wtf ?

```
pi@local:~ $ sudo su - root
root@local:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah the file I was looking for was /etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd, solved now.